# Enforce Object Property to be serializable

Tags: c#, serialization, interface, properties

I am building a class and in the interface for my class(es) I have a property declared

```
object MyObject { get; set; }
```

What I want to do is force whatever is stored in MyObject to be serializable.  Is there a good way to do this?

Normally, I'd use where : ISerializable, but for serialization you use an attribute, not inheritance, or at least that is my assumption.

Comment: Have you tried this: ISerializable MyObject { get; set; }  Not sure if it would work.

Comment: That didn't work, but thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never could figure out how to enforce a class be Serializable.  I had to move away from generic classes anyway for other reasons, so through inheritance I just create a property for my object to be serialized and serialize/deserialize it in the set/get accessors and store the serialized string in a string property in the base class, which is inherited.